# Can I generate a custom resumeAfter token (based on time) for mongodb change streams?

Tags: mongodb, changestream

In change streams I can provide a resumeAfter token which I can get from a previous change by accessing `change._id`.

Can I generate my own a token that is based on timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

I can use `startAtOperationTime` timestamp instead of resumeAfter. In mongo 4.